# Complex numbers inequality with geometric interpretation

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb C$ so as $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$ and let $a=|z_1-z_2|, b=|z_2-z_3|, c=|z_3-z_1|$. Show that:a+b+c<3.

Comment: Do you already have a proof? If so put it in question, and then ask for geometric interpretation.

Comment: I don't have the proof. I don't know how to start. For the geometric interpretation, I think it is: In every triangle ABC with circumradius equal to 1 the following inequality holds.

Comment: The geometric interpretation is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using Holder's inequality 
$$LHS\cdot \left(\sum_{cyc} (a+b-c)\right)^2\ge 27$$

Hence it is enough to prove the perimeter of any triangle inscribed in the unit circle is $\le 3\sqrt3$. Can you fill the gaps and complete now?

Comment: Thank you! I also managed to prove it with Euler's inequality. But I was looking to a more "algebraic" solution, not including geometry. That was the purpose of the problem.

Comment: Do you see any algebraic solution?